# Добрый день. Не могли бы вы помочь решить задачу в python?

Tags: python

Дано целое число K. Вывести строку-описание оценки, соответствующей числу K                                                                          (1 «плохо», 2 «неудовлетворительно»,  3 «удовлетворительно», 4 «хорошо», 5 «отлично»).
 Если K не лежит в диапазоне 1–5, то вывести строку «ошибка».

Comment: "помочь" - облегчить кому-либо выполнение какого-нибудь дела. Вы уже выполняете дело? Если нет, то и помогать не с чем.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну блин) он наверное только начинает учить, почему бы и не помочь, вряд ли он за это деньги получит.

Answer (score 1):

```
k = int(input('Введите число: '))
if k == 1:
   print('Плохо')
elif k == 2:
   print('неудовлетворительно') 
elif k == 3:
   print('удовлетворительно')
elif k == 4:
   print ('хорошо') 
elif k == 5:
   print('отлично') 
else:
   print('Ошибка')
```

Comment: почему минусовали, ответ вроде подходящий

Comment: @MidNightElf В том то и дело) некоторые люди считают что вопросы такого вида, не заслуживают ответа)

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, скоро будет удален, а вместе с ним и ответ. А вместе с ним и голоса за и против, включая баллы за репутацию. Так что зря старался. Оказал медвежью услугу и остался ни с чем.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну зачем ты так? :)

Comment: Как "так"? Говорю как есть. Ленивые халявщики помощи не заслуживают, а ты только зря потратил время. Он тебе даже спасибо не скажет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Мне кажется это просто новичек, который не хочет учить 'теорию', а хочет сразу писать код, но у него ничего не получается, или просто может не может сдать предмет в универе, думаешь он деньги получит за эту ерунду?)

Comment: да, думаю, что он за это получит 3400 рублей.

Comment: @Эникейщик правда? Откуда информация? Если подтвердится то удаляю ответ!!

Comment: Что, самому хочется 3400 получить? :D

Comment: @Эникейщик За такой код, да :)